# Matplotlib Trisurf doesn't work properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, surface, scatter

I am trying to make a surface out of a bunch of scattered data.

Here is an image of the scattered data: [image]

And here is the code:

```
#A lot of code for making the data, saved in lists (or arrays, it doesn't 
change the plot)#
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.scatter(Y,T,X)
ax.set_xlabel("p1")
ax.set_xlim(0.0,np.max(Y))
ax.set_ylabel("p3")
ax.set_ylim(0.0,np.max(T))
ax.set_zlabel("p0")
ax.set_zlim(0.0,np.max(X))
ax.view_init(azim=50)
ax.set_title(" for " + str(dN)+ " takes "+ str(datetime.now()-startTime))
plt.show()
```

Now, in order to create a surface I read that the best way, when you are dealing with 3D points of data, is using the trisurf function.

Therefore, I write

```
 ax.plot_trisurf(Y, T, X,cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
```

instead of the

```
ax.scatter(...)
```

However, the plot I get is:
[image]

Which is completely different from the Scatter plot!

Is there another way of making this surface??
If you need to see from where I get the data I can write the hole code, so let me know.

Thanks.

EDIT: I also tried another kind of surface, using the wireframe function. However, the surface I get is not smooth. And I don't know any other fuction to make this plot.

[image]
If is there no other fuction, I would try to use the wireframe and try to smooth it somehow. Any suggestion?

Comment: what do the other 3D surface functions give you?

Comment: @PaulH I just edited the post. I used the wireframe fuction, however it doesn't give me a smooth fuction, and it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: there are lots of functions in the matplotlib docs, do none of them work?

Comment: @PaulH to my knowledge, the only remaining is the surface function. However, I tried it, trying to map de data to a 2D grid in order to work, and I got nothing, a null plot.

Comment: My main concern, is that the Trisurf fuction is said to be the best for this things and I get thay bad plot and I dont know why

Comment: maybe your data isn't appropriate for a trisurf plot. it looks more like a volume to me.

Comment: @PaulH well, yes, it is indeed a volume. Maybe that's why Trisurf doesn't work well.

Comment: I try doing some more research in this topic, searching some packages for visualitzing volumes. Thanks

Comment: When you use trisurf you need to provide a connectivity. What is the connectivity for your data?

Comment: @nicoguaro I don't know thay a connectivity is. I just have a bunch of data scattered in a 3D space that represents a volume.

Comment: Then your first step is to create a triangulation for the surface of your volume.

Comment: @nicoguaro Can you give me some link where I can find how to do it??

Comment: If your points form a convex shape, then you can compute the convex hull of it. ``scipy.spatial`` has this algorithm. You could try with [Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/) to generate the mesh